# Program is stop when I call Qfiledialog in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1093, 670)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 320, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        ...

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButtonClicked)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))




    def pushButtonClicked(self):
        print("hi")
        dialog = QFileDialog
        dialog.show()
        ##dialog.getOpenFileName(None,tr("Open Image"), "/home", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I make this code from PYQT5 Designer and I want to open QFileDialog to choose file.
But when I click button which connet to pushButtonClicked, the program is stop and crash.
Please help me

Comment: Please post the full stack trace from the crash.

Comment: What do expect the line `dialog = QFileDialog` to do?

Comment: Change `dialog = QFileDialog` to `dialog = QFileDialog(self)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it this way:

```
def pushButtonClicked(self):
    self.op_dir = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,tr("Open Image"), "/home", tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"))
```

And the variable `self.op_dir` will contain your selected path

Answer (score 0):

```
path_to_project = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, tr("Open Directory"), "C:/", QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly|QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)
```

did not work for me either. It crashed when called.
However, removing the translate function tr() and just put in the string solved the problem:

```
path_to_project = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Open Directory", "C:/", QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly|QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks)
```